# String crashing when passing through urlize

Tags: django

When I try to pass the content of a TextField that contains characters like í ó ú ñ etc it crashes. I tried doing string.encode('utf-8') and putting # encoding: utf-8 in top of the views file and the file that has the urlize filter. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Please define "it crashes." Did you receive an error message? Please post the relevant snippets of your code so we can provide specific direction.

Comment: @George, this is the error message I get "UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 13-15: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: this is what I'm doing inside views.py str(linebreaks(urlize(p.content)))

Comment: I just tried this, but no avail: str(linebreaks(urlize(p.content, None, False, True)))

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a link to code to help with the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize), `urlize` converts URLs in text into clickable links. According to [RFC1728](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), URLs can contains only "graphic printable characters of the US-ASCII coded character set."

The characters you mentioned are not part of the required ASCII subset, so `urlize` can be expected to fail. You will need to escape your input to remove such characters. UTF-8 is valid for the contents of an HTML document, but not for a URL.

Your UTF-8 content can be converted to ASCII using the snippet found here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/588/

Comment: So I should force it into US-ASCII before sending it to urlize, how can I do that?

Comment: @madprops: Before you do that, consider the output. If you force the specific text to ASCII, will the resulting URL be valid?

Comment: @madprops: Additionally, an answer to my original comment would be helpful.

Comment: It's not crashing now but it strips away the non ASCII characters and I need them. I did this .encode('ascii', 'ignore')

Comment: @madprops: Then you are at an impasse. `urlize` will only work with ASCII input, but you say you need the non-ASCII characters. You will have to choose whether to use urlize, or to keep the non-ASCII characters.